# Xamarin.Android bindingtool ignoring classes

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having some issues creating a binding for Kontakt.io's Android SDK v1.0.6 - https://github.com/kontaktio/Android-SDK/tree/master/1.0.6.

I'm "almost done" (famous last words, huh?) but for some reason, some classes are being outright ignored. In particular, AbstractModel is being ignored, despite adding this to my metadata.xml file:

```xml
<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.android.connection']/interface[@name='BeaconConnection.WriteBatchListener']/method[@name='onErrorOccured']" name="managedName">onBatchErrorOccured</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.android.connection']/interface[@name='BeaconConnection.ConnectionListener']/method[@name='onErrorOccured']" name="managedName">onConnectionErrorOccured</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.android.manager']/class" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.android.model']/class[@name='AbstractModel']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
</metadata>
```

I get around 100 errors due to that class not being generated - no warnings and the file isn't under the generated/src folder. Is it possible to get a more verbose output from bindingtool?

After decompiling the jar, the only "odd" thing that I notice is that it's one of the few classes implementing Parcelable.

```
abstract class AbstractModel implements Parcelable {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasn't being generated (or at least hidden from eagle-eye view) since it required a visibility override:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.android.model']/class[@name='AbstractModel']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.